# Pyspark spark.sql MERGE based on PRIMARY KEYs & A CONDITION

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, apache-spark-sql

I have a source & target tables.  I need to merge my source dataset into the target table based on Primary Keys.  Following is the representative schema for the 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `master_data` (
  `cust_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `active_flg` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cust_number`,`zip_code`)
)

CREATE TABLE `delta_data` (
  `cust_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cust_number`,`zip_code`)
)
```

In the master table there could many duplicate records based on the PRIMARY key, but uniqueness would be based on the ACTIVE_FLG, which there would be only one record.

```
cust_number zip_code start_date end_date active_flg
1   21034 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 N
1   21034 01/01/2017 31/12/2018 N
1   21034 01/01/2018 31/12/2019 Y
```

Any delta record I recieve for customer number/zip_code (1, 21034) should merge if there is one record ACTIVE FLG as Y else insert the record.

Delta record:

```
cust_number zip_code state country name
 1   21034 CA US Stephen
```

Is there a way to achieve this conditional merge like this please.  I need to use MERGE into TABLE ... ON ... WHEN MATCHED < > WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT.

I tried the following but am getting merge failure due to duplicate primary records found.

```
Merge into master_data md 
using delta_data dd 
on md.cust_number = dd.cust_number 
and md.zip_code = dd.zip_code 
and md.active_flg = 'Y'
when matched <UPDATE>
when not matched <INSERT>
```

Thanks,

Yuva

Comment: _In the master table there could many duplicate records based on the PRIMARY key_ That is not right. A PRIMARY KEY is allways unique, it can't have any duplicates. So the data you set in your first table could never be there

Comment: yeah correct, but unfortunately i dont have a control over it, is there a way to MERGE against the active_flg value in master table.  Please note that is not part of delta file, but simply have see if there is an active record. thanks

Comment: You need [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY .. UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Mysql does not have merge see insert on duplicate key..

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle tags if you are using MySQL?

Comment: were you doing this thing in Spark?